# HTML Partials with rails 6 and webpacker not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, webpack, webpacker, html-webpack-plugin

I'd like to load an html partial in with webpack. From what I can tell this config is correct. I don't get any errors, so I'm wondering what else might be up. Maybe somehow I'm not utilizing webpack somehow in my rails app?

Webpacker Config (environments.js)

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPartialsPlugin = require('html-webpack-partials-plugin')

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
)
environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new HtmlWebpackPartialsPlugin({
    path: path.join(__dirname, './partials/ga.html'),
    location: 'head',
    priority: 'high'
  })
)

module.exports = environment;
```

ga.html

```
<script> alert('testing!') </script>
```

Thoughts? Ideas? What am I missing here?